# SmtpMail - Change the "From Address" to Name

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp

I use SmtpMail for users to forward site content. The user fills out a form which includes first name and email.

The email sent has the full email address as the "From address" in the recipients inbox (they see From: Joe@Gmail.com while I want them to see From: Joe).

How can I format the "From address" to be the users inputted first name?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format I ended up using was: `mailer.From = name & "<" & emailer & ">"`

This formats the from address to include Name as well as Email address. It will be displayed in most email clients as `Joe <Joe@email.com>`. This was my desired outcome.

Thank you Knslyr and lincolnk for the support.

Answer (score 2):

The [MailAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1s17zfkf.aspx) class has an optional parameter where you can specify a display name. I assume it will be used when present.

```
Dim from As MailAddress = New MailAddress("ben@contoso.com", "Ben Miller")
Dim to As MailAddress = New MailAddress("jane@contoso.com", "Jane Clayton")
Dim message As MailMessage = New MailMessage(from, to)
```

Comment: This is causing the page not to load... any ideas?

Comment: Below is the code section that passes the main mail variables. "receiver, emailer, nombre" are the 3 variables pulled from the form. I need "nombre" to be passed through the mailer.from field instead of emailer. 


<code>mailer.To = receiver
mailer.Bcc = "Bcc@test.com"
mailer.From = emailer
mailer.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html
mailer.Subject = "Subject Line Here"</code>

Answer (score 2):

This has always worked for me:

```
    Dim myMessage As New MailMessage

    Dim myFrom As MailAddress = New MailAddress("bob@contoso.com", "Bob Denver")
    Dim myTo As MailAddress = New MailAddress("steve@contoso.com", "Steve Miller")

    myMessage.From = myFrom
    myMessage.To.Add(myTo)
```

Answer (score 0):

this method displays 'Rameez' instead of 'Rameez@abc.com.pk'

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim objRecip As Recipient
    Dim strMsg As String
    Dim res As Integer
    Dim strBcc As String
    On Error Resume Next

    strBcc = """Rameez"" <Rameez@abc.com.pk>"

    Set objRecip = Item.Recipients.Add(strBcc)
    objRecip.Type = olBCC
        If Not objRecip.Resolve Then
            strMsg = "Could not resolve the Bcc recipient. " & _
            "Do you want still to send the message?"
            res = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton1, _
            "Could Not Resolve Bcc Recipient")
            If res = vbNo Then
                Cancel = True
            End If
        End If
    Set objRecip = Nothing

    End Sub
```